# Invalid Pointer Operation TXMLDocument

Tags: c++builder-xe2

I am having some problems with an application. It used to work just fine but today when i ran it again to test it a bit more I got some `Invalid Pointer Operation` exceptions.

This is some part of the code:
Here I declare:

```
TXMLDocument *xml;
```

And a few lines below I construct it:

```
xml = new TXMLDocument(NULL);
```

And then a few lines below the construction I am loading the xml and then trying to access the root node named "root":

```
xml->LoadFromXML(AnsiString(final_xml.c_str()));

//at the line below i am getting the Invalid Pointer Operation exception.
_di_IXMLNodeList root = xml->ChildNodes->GetNode("root")->GetChildNodes();
```

At the end of the function I am deleting the xml:

```
delete xml;
```

Here you can find the whole function:
http://pastebin.com/MpRf8Gfn

The strange thing is that it used to work find and now I am getting this error out from nowhere (I have changed nothing in the source code for about a month and it used to work fine).

If anyone has any idea why would this error pop up I would be grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think i found out what the "error" is...It is mentioned in the documentation that with COM objects the interface_cast should be used to ensure the correct lifespan of the object(aka to increase the reference counters properly for that item).

Comment: You should release `root` before doing `delete xml;`. ALso your `try..catch` blocks leak memory if they throw. Instead of using a raw pointer and delete, consider using `unique_ptr` which will automatically delete on its scope ending.

Comment: Also, when you get the invalid operation in the debugger, take note of which line failed, that should give you a clue.

Comment: I've always used `TComInterface` rather than `_di_` as I've been unable to find any info on how the `_di_` versions work, so am a bit iffy about it!

Comment: Ok thanks for the information :)...I had located the line with the problem with the help of the debugger but i couldn't just figure out what the problem was until recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the documentation, creating a `TXMLDocument` instance with a `NULL` owner causes it to act like a reference counted interfaced object instead of a normal object.  As such, you need to follow proper reference counting semantics, which you are not doing, hence the crashing.

The best way to do that in this situation is to use `LoadXMLData()` and `_di_IXMLDocument`, eg:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::dataUpload2ServerServe(TCustomIpClient *ClientSocket)
{
    _di_IXMLDocument xml;
    ...
    xml = LoadXMLData(final_xml.c_str());
    _di_IXMLNodeList root = xml->DocumentElement->ChildNodes;
    ...
    xml->SaveToFile(filename);
    ...
}
```

When the `xml` and `root` variables go out of scope, they will automatically decrement the reference counts for you.  If you want to "free" them manually, you can simply assign NULL to them:

```
root = NULL;
xml = NULL;
```

Or call their `Release()` method:

```
root.Release();
xml.Release();
```